# How can I modify a GIF that uses "cumulative layers"?

Tags: gimp, images, animation

When you save a GIF in GIMP, you're given the option to use **cumulative layers (combine)** or **one frame per layer (replace)**.

Choosing **cumulative layers** causes the GIF's layers to only contain the pixels that changed since the last frame.

Choosing **one frame per layer** causes each of the GIF's layers to save all of its pixels, not relying on any of the pixels from the last frame.

If a GIF has been previously saved with cumulative layers, and I delete the first few frames, it messes up the rest of the GIF because the later frames were relying on the (now deleted) color information from the first frames.

Here's an example:

**Original:**

[image]

**After deleting the first two frames:**

[image]

How can I save the modified GIF so that it looks correct?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is real easy in gimp. You unoptimize the gif to reveal all pixel data in layers (filters/animation/unoptimize). Delete the layers, 2 first in your case, then optimize it again (filters/animation/optimize for gif) Export as gif, tick the animation box.

Comment: Perfect! I wasn't aware of the unoptimize feature.

Answer (score 3):

The whole idea behind **Cumulative (Combine)** is to cut down the size of the file by eliminating the parts that don't change and keeping the bits that do. If you want to go the **Replace** route (and I can't imagine why, but okay), make a copy of the first layer and merge the copy with the next layer up. Then make a copy of the new layer and merge *that* with the next layer up. And so on, ad naus. Save as animation.

Yes, it's a rather clunky solution.

Comment: That would be very tedious if the GIF has 100 frames. Do you know if there's any way to automate it?  Photoshop has a way of doing it automatically.

Comment: Also, I renamed the title of the post. I don't actually care if the new GIF uses Replace or Combine, but it has to look correct.

Comment: Tedious? You betcha. I honestly don't know about automating the process, I don't play with GIFs much. Somebody clever with Python could probably come up with a script.

Answer (score 0):

To make it less clunky I created a merge down shortcut in gimp.

The duplicate layer shortcut is: ctrl+shift D

i created a merge down shortcut in preferences like so so i can leave the figers on the ctrl+shift button.

ctrl+shift M

Then start at background layer (bottom one) and do:

ctrl+shift D > arrow up > ctrl+shift M

and so on

when finished export as gif there you can choose the "framedisposal where unspecified" to safe it as "one frame per layer (replace)"

Comment: Welcome! Can you please add one or  more screenshots to show the way? Thanks!